# Shiny with more than one optional input for a single table output

Tags: r, shiny, multiple-input

all.

I would like to create a shiny script to perform some analysis. One of the first steps is to ensure that people have the correct input. There is one major input that are several files in a folder, 2 mandatory tsv/txt inputs and 3 optional tsv/txt ones. The optional ones are independent, meaning I could have any combination of them present, or none.

Each tsv/txt have some information in lines that are supposed to be added as a column to my output, a dataframe of sorts.

As of right now, my code is able to receive the mandatory inputs and show the output with the correct row names and the 2 mandatory input information as columns.

I am struggling to find a way to process the optional inputs. I don't think the `req()` statement will do, because it may hold the execution while it is waiting for one of the optional inputs that may never come.

I thought about placing a send button and watch for the action with `observeEvent()` but it will throw an error for being inside `renderTable()`.

Well, this is my code. The auxiliary functions are weird, in my real code they are processing the files using a very specific package that I took out of this minimal working example. I commented the part that is not working. Input test files are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fnexdift7e708u0/AADUDJwbn08bKGcpbrpk2tola?dl=0).

```
library(shiny)

read_and_rename_my_files <- function(input_from_shiny) {
  n_rows <- length(input_from_shiny$name)
  cel_files <- data.frame(1:n_rows)
  rownames(cel_files) <- input_from_shiny$name
  
  return(cel_files)
}

read_file_content_from_column <- function(path_file, 
                                          i_col = 1){
  if (file.exists(path_file)) {
    content <- read.table(file = path_file,
                          header = F)[, i_col]
    return(content)
  } else {
    stop(sprintf(fmt = 'File >%s< not found.',
                 path_arq))
  }
}

edit_mydata <- function(mydata_obj,
                        path_arq,
                        n_col_mydata,
                        name_col_mydata){
  
  content <- read_file_content_from_column(path_file = path_arq)
  
  mydata_obj[, n_col_mydata] <- content
  colnames(mydata_obj)[n_col_mydata] = name_col_mydata
  return(mydata_obj)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(title = "Stack overflow is great", 
             tabPanel(title = "Data Input", 
                      fluid = TRUE, 
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                                                    
                                                    # File uploads
                                                    fileInput(inputId = 'main_input', 
                                                              label = 'the content of the provided folder: use ctrl + A to add all files.', 
                                                              multiple=TRUE, 
                                                              accept = c("text/csv",
                                                                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                                                         ".csv")),
                                                    fileInput(inputId = "mandatory_input1", 
                                                              label = "Choose TSV file with sample names",
                                                              multiple = FALSE,
                                                              accept = c("text/csv",
                                                                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                                                         ".csv")),
                                                    fileInput(inputId = "mandatory_input2", 
                                                              label = "Choose TSV file with experimental conditions",
                                                              multiple = FALSE,
                                                              accept = c("text/csv",
                                                                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                                                         ".csv")),
                                                    tags$hr(),
                                                    
                                                    fileInput(inputId = "optional_input1", 
                                                              label = "Optional: choose TSV file with another grouping variable",
                                                              multiple = FALSE,
                                                              accept = c("text/csv",
                                                                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                                                         ".csv")),
                                                    textInput(inputId = "optional_input1_name",
                                                              label = "Input grouping variable name",
                                                              #value = "group",
                                                              placeholder = "Ex: ageGroup")#,
                                                    
                        ),
                        # Main Panel for dataInput
                        mainPanel = mainPanel(
                          tableOutput(outputId = "contents")
                        )))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$contents <- renderTable(rownames = T, 
                                 expr = {
                                   
                                   req(input$main_input)
                                   files.cel <- read_and_rename_my_files(input$main_input)
                                   
                                   req(input$mandatory_input1)
                                   files.cel <- edit_mydata(mydata_obj = files.cel,
                                                            path_arq = input$mandatory_input1$datapath,
                                                            n_col_mydata = 1,
                                                            name_col_mydata = "Sample_names")
                                   
                                   req(input$mandatory_input2)
                                   files.cel <- edit_mydata(mydata_obj = files.cel,
                                                            path_arq = input$mandatory_input2$datapath,
                                                            n_col_mydata = 2,
                                                            name_col_mydata = "Conditions")

                                   # observeEvent(eventExpr = input$groupingButton,
                                   #              handlerExpr = {
                                   #                pData(files.cel) <- edit_pdata(pdata_obj = pData(files.cel),
                                   #                                               path_arq = input$GROUPING_FILE$datapath,
                                   #                                               n_col_pdata = ncol(pData(files.cel)) + 1,
                                   #                                               name_col_pdata = "Grouping")})
                                   
                                 }
  ) 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

All suggestions are appreciated. I am open to redesigning the whole thing. Thank you all in advance.

Bonus question:
I have a textbox input to receive the name of the optional input 1. Any ideas on how to use that too?

Comment: I'd break it down into separate steps. 1) create reactive objects to store mandatory and optional files 2) tohse reactive would be populated in `observeEvent` conneted to specific fileInput 3) rendering a table could be triggered by separate button that would be observed separately.

Comment: `req` is powered by a handy function called `isTruthy`. Instead of breaking out of your reactive expression it just returns `FALSE` for inputs that would fail `req`. It's useful for optional parameters like this.